# Steps to create Webservice/WCFservice and host in sitecore folder

Tags: sitecore

Could anyone point me to the steps to host/publish the webservice/wcf service in sitecore/shell/webservice folder.
I have created the service and published to /sitecore/shell/webservice folder it throws authentication error and after that service host error. The need is to deploy the service in a folder where all the sitecore contents are accessible.

Comment: What kind of error is it? Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

Two good resources for this:

- http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/make-sitecore-host-wcf/
- http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2009/03/attach-wcf-services-to-sitecore-context.html

Comment: I have tried both the steps, unfortunately both are not working for me

Comment: As mentioned in the •http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/make-sitecore-host-wcf/ we are supposed to create service as a part of vstudio solution, which I dont want todo. Basically as per the blog  •http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2009/03/attach-wcf-services-to-sitecore-context.html creating wcf service outside and hosting is throwing authentication and service host issues. Let me know if anyone has tried this approach and workign for them.